# Exclude/omit common attributes between two types recursively

Tags: typescript

Assuming that we have the following two types:

```js
type One = {
  one: number;
  two?: number;
  three: number;
  sub: {
    two?: number;
    three: number;
  }
}

type Two = {
  three: number;
}
```

I want to exclude common attributes between those types, so the new type should be like this:

```js
type Three = {
  one: number;
  two?: number;
  sub: {
    two?: number;
  }
}
```

I tried this type, but the result wasn’t recursive:

```js
type ExcludeType<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof K>>;
type Three = ExcludeType<One, Two>;
// didn’t exclude `three` in `sub`
```

So I modified it a little bit to make it recursive, but it made all attributes as required:

```js
type ExcludeCommonRecursively<T, K> = {
  [U in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]: T[U] extends U
  ? ExcludeCommonRecursively<T[U], K>
  : T[U] extends U[]
  ? ExcludeCommonRecursively<T[U][number], K>[]
  : T[U];
}
type Three = ExcludeCommonRecursively<One, Two>;
// it made `two?` as required
```

Comment: I don't see what `Two` really has to do with this; it looks like you just want to use `keyof Two`.  So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ1Prm) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! The only issue with it that typescript can't infer the type directly, but at least it works as expected.

Comment: I don't understand what type you want it to infer, but it sounds like a followup issue to me so I'm not going to worry about it. I'll write up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a recursive version of [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys). Let's call that `RecursiveOmit<T, K>`. Here's one way to write it:

```
type RecursiveOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  T extends object ? {
    [P in keyof T as Exclude<P, K>]: RecursiveOmit<T[P], K>
  } : T;
```

That's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which checks if the input type is primitive and returns it as-is.  If the input type is a non-primitive type (i.e., a subtype of [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type)) then we use the key filtering feature of [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to suppress any properties in `K` from appearing (via [`Exclude<P, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)).  And for each property key `P` that is included, we transform the property type from `T[P]` to `RecursiveOmit<T[P], K>`.

Let's test it out:

```
type Three = RecursiveOmit<One, "three">;
/* type Three = {
    one: number;
    two?: number;
    sub: {
        two?: number;
    };
} */
```

Looks good.

---

If you want to turn that into a version that accepts an *object type* instead a union of its keys, you can wrap it with [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator):

```
type RecursiveOmitKeysOf<T, U> = RecursiveOmit<T, keyof U>;   

type Two = { three: number; }
type Four = RecursiveOmitKeysOf<One, Two>;
/* type Four = {
    one: number;
    two?: number;
    sub: {
        two?: number;
    };
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdtAvFA3gKClA9ggXFOAVwFsAjCAJwG4MpgB3LAfnyLMps2AAsKIJWJctVoBnQqXzpMXRiwJCOtLr36D2IzAF80OtKEhQAShADGhCqICWANwgxiV4AB4AKgBooAaSgQAHsAQcAAmolAAChRYkBSgXhAgAHxQiLSuvgFBodikAFZmwFBMqMpQANrhUFZwUADWCVgAZlDpAIZhAKJ+pgA2hMEQzuGeXokAuvgm5pa29o4urhVjI4m0WlD4rjT64NCuqkjGZhbWdg5OzvAQngBEPHwQN4k0APQAVHS7LQcpJTLYeAUGk4MgYzHUwhBmHEkj+-1BcghSn+Who6zeLzQO0MUxOs3OwHiIFEMEabk8AFVkshcTMzvNyXUGs0qdtsXtGL8UHQDkjqFAdAZoAAxLAWX6005zJxEklkq6eVyMZ5od6fQyi8XIaQyHACIGQ0pg+RsQ3-GFSUr-Y18qECtFQDFoIA)